# How to implement Expandable - Collapsable UITableViewCell in UITableView - IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I took approach of the `UITableview` to get cell click `ExpandView`. I want something like this to be implement.

[image: Exapand cell View]

So, `UITableView` would be best approach for this or suggest me any good way of implementing, also I am not able to get `subview` to adjust according to `screenSize`.

Comment: You are looking for a kind of accordion UITableView.
Here a nice tutorial about that. Check http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/expandable-collapsable-accordio-uitableview/. Hope that helps, regards.

Answer (score 3):

Could be there are another ways to accomplish this but this is how I am expand `UITableViewCell` on the fly. This could give the idea and you can implement your solution.

I keep row heights in my data model:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Data source
    datasource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *aDicti = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [aDicti setValue:@"a TEXT" forKey:@"text"];
    [aDicti setValue:@(50) forKey:@"cellheight"]; // here
}
```

When selection changed, just updating related key in data source.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [[datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@(50) forKey:@"cellheight"];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [[datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@(200) forKey:@"cellheight"];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Once [tableView endUpdates]; executed `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate methods fired and automatically adjust cell height with the value from data source.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [[[datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cellheight"] intValue];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return datasource.count;
}
```

**If you do not want to keep row height in your data source you can basically apply this.**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row == indexPath.row) {
        return 100;
    }
    return 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`SDNestedTable`](https://github.com/robelkin/ios-SDNestedTables) does exactly what you want.

> The module concept is that of having all the default functionality of
>   a `UITableView` and its cells while at the same time adding for each
>   cell a child `UITableView`. Each cell (`SDGroupCell`) in the main
>   `SDNestedTableViewController` tableview acts as controller for its own
>   sub table. The state, population and behavior of the table and
>   subtable is instead mostly controlled by
>   `SDNestedTableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

That's call, **accordion**, this site having good examples (with demos) for it, [here's the link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=accordion).

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you are working with TableView you should play with number of section headers and cells.
In case of using section headers you should set numberOfRowsInSection to 0 (roll up) to X when you want to expand it. After that call

```
tableView.reloadData
```

I implemented this behavior here, with animation, with different heights:

https://github.com/rudald/expandedTableViewIOSSwift/

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous open source projects regarding this feature. I've downloaded a few projects and the most customizable and issue-less, for me, was [SLExpandableTableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView)

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking for a straight forward easy-to-setup library for expandable views, [HVTableView](https://github.com/innovian/HVTableView) is your choice. It provides an acceptable performance which is sufficient for using in regular projects.