# UITableViewCell expand animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to make something like expandable cells. Result I'm trying to achieve is:
[image: What I want]

Actually I have:

[image: What I have]

Here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DoctorCell *cell = self.prototypeCell;
    DoctorModel *doctor = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:frcIndexPath];

    // depending on isActive property I add (or do not add) some content.
    [cell cellForDoctor:doctor isActiveCell:[self.activeCellIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]];
    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    return height + 1;
}
```

Here is my cell selection method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = self.activeCellIndexPath;
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.activeCellIndexPath]) {
        self.activeCellIndexPath = nil;
        oldIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        self.activeCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    [self.doctorTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.doctorTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, oldIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.doctorTableView endUpdates];

    [self.doctorTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

As you can see, my animation looks weird (kind of moving to wrong position, jumps, etc). What I'm doing wrong? Or do I need to pick another approach for expanding cells?

Comment: Please have a look my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056565/how-to-implement-expandable-collapsable-uitableviewcell-in-uitableview-ios/25057523#25057523). It describe pretty much same thing and it could give idea to you.

Comment: @mohacs this is exactly what I'm doing here, it has weird animation

Comment: what do you mean weird, as I can see it looks ok to me. You might want to try other libraries. Here is the [link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=accordion) to one of them.

Comment: @mohacs as you can see on the 1st gif when bottom row is clicked it moves up and shows whole row. On the 2nd gif same action give the different result - buttons are hidden

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UITableView`s animation automation like this:

1. Call `[tableView beginUpdates];`
2. Change the data source.
3. Insert or delete rows and sections, or reload them

   - This should cause new heights to be calculated, etc.
   - Make sure you use something appropriate for the `withRowAnimation` parameter of these methods
4. Call `[tableView endUpdates];`

Your animation should now perform as expected.

Maybe your problem is that you selected `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` for the row animation.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm doing. I reload rows with `[self.doctorTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`. Is it ok?

Comment: I am sure the last edit solved your problem. Please accept this answer.